# Generate a word file from template and XML data

Tags: c#, ms-word, word-2007

I would like to generate on-the-fly word documents from a template and a XML file of which XSD is known.

Is there any best practice known to achieve it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use custom xml data binding.  See generally http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff433638.aspx

Comment: It is just my opinion or xml data bounding works bad if I want a section of the document to be repeated based on XML multiplicity?

Comment: see my opendope.org for a way around this, or wait for Word 2013.